# Duplicate words in a text

Tags: java, stream, lambda, set

Here is a simplified implementation to obtain the duplicate words in a text using lambda expressions.

```
public class FindDuplicateWordsInText {

    public static Set<String> findDuplicateWordsInText(String text) {
        String[] words = text.split(" ");
        Set<String> duplicatesRemovedSet = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> duplicatesSet = Arrays.stream(words).filter(string -> !duplicatesRemovedSet.add(string))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return duplicatesSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your main concern?

Comment: Lambda, not lamba

Answer (score 4):

Your use of the boolean return value of the `Set.add()` call is a clever way to check for your duplicates. The concept you have is good, and I can't think of a faster way.

Additionally, I like how you have used Interface-based types on the left-side of assignments `Set<String>` and the concrete classes on the right `new HashSet<>()` .... people often put the concrete type on the left too, and it's good to see that you did not.

In terms of the Java streaming API, though, I can't help but feel that you missed out on an opportunity to improve the process by streaming the split.... The Pattern class has a splitAsStream method which would reduce your latency on the first words....

As an aside, a word should probably be on a contiguous whitespace, not just a single space (i.e. `"\\s+"` instead of `" "`).

Here's your code done differently:

```
private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile("\\s+");

public static Set<String> findDuplicateWordsInText(String text) {
    Set<String> duplicatesRemovedSet = new HashSet<>();
    return SPACE.splitAsStream(text)
            .filter(string -> !duplicatesRemovedSet.add(string))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The implementation seems fine. I would change the return type of the method to be a bit more general. Callers don't care about whether the duplicates are stored in a Set or not.

```
public static Collection<String> findDuplicateWordsInText(String text) {
    String[] words = text.split(" ");
    Set<String> duplicatesRemovedSet = new HashSet<>();
    List<String> duplicates = Arrays.stream(words).filter(
            string -> !duplicatesRemovedSet.add(string)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return duplicates;
}
```

But honestly, using stream/filter doesn't make it much clearer. Why not stick with the standard approach?

```
public static Collection<String> findDuplicateWordsInText(String text) {
    String[] words = text.split(" ");
    List<String> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<String> duplicatesRemovedSet = new HashSet<>();
    for (String word: words) {
        if (!duplicatesRemovedSet.add(word)) {
            duplicates.add(word);
        }
    }       
    return duplicates;
}
```

Comment: A `Set` has no duplicates. :)

Comment: "Callers don't care about whether the duplicates are stored in a Set or not" - what if I want to find duplicate words and then pass them into another method that accepts a `Set<String>`? Callers benefit when a method has general input types and a specific output type.

Answer (score 1):

`Set.add(...)` has side effects by nature, which means that your `filter` method isn't "pure". In the given example, I don't see a concrete downside, but if you later wanted to make the stream parallel, you'd need to use a concurrent `Set`.

For comparison, here's a side-effect free solution using Guava's `Multiset`:

```
public static Set<String> findDuplicateWordsInText(String text) {
  Multiset<String> wordMultiset =
      ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(Splitter.on(' ').split(text));
  return wordMultiset.entrySet()
      .stream()
      .filter(entry -> entry.getCount() > 1)
      .map(Multiset.Entry::getElement)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

It probably doesn't perform as well, but the intent should (*hopefully*) come across clearly.